# Changing Footnote numbering fails for some word documents with Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I have the following code being used with Word 2016 installed, referencing `Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library`:

```
private void RefreshFootnoteNumbering(FileManagement.FileManager FileManager)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Refreshing footnotes DOCX");

    // Opening and saving in word generates the required element
    var Word = GetWordApp();
    try
    {
        var DocxPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, Path.ChangeExtension(FileManager.HtmlFileLocation, "docx"));
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\tOpening document");
        var Doc = GetWordDoc(Word, DocxPath);
        try
        {
            // Fails on these lines below (both cause the same exception)
            Doc.Footnotes.NumberingRule = InteropWord.WdNumberingRule.wdRestartPage;
            Doc.Footnotes.Location = InteropWord.WdFootnoteLocation.wdBottomOfPage;

            Doc.SaveAs2(DocxPath, InteropWord.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles: false, EmbedTrueTypeFonts: true);
        }
        finally
        {
            Doc.Close();
            Doc = null;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Word.Quit();
        Word = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
}
```

This works for most documents, however for some I get the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2146823680
  HResult=-2146823680
  HelpLink=wdmain11.chm#37376
  Message=Value out of range
  Source=Microsoft Word
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Footnotes.set_NumberingRule(WdNumberingRule prop)
```

Other interop functions (iterating/manipulating fields, sections etc) work fine, it seems to be just altering footnotes in this way that have an issue. Altering them from within Word itself works fine.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Any work arounds or alternatives?

---

I've tried recording a macro, and it gave this VBA code:

```
With ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=ActiveDocument.Content.Start, End:= _
    ActiveDocument.Content.End).FootnoteOptions
    .Location = wdBottomOfPage
    .NumberingRule = wdRestartContinuous
    .StartingNumber = 1
    .NumberStyle = wdNoteNumberStyleArabic
    .NumberingRule = wdRestartPage
    .LayoutColumns = 0
End With
```

If I run this macro, I get the same error (value out of range, error number 4608) on the `.Location` line, whether I run from the debugger, or just view macros -> run.

I've also tried to translate that VBA into C# code:

```
var Options = Doc.Range(Doc.Content.Start, Doc.Content.End).FootnoteOptions;

Options.Location = InteropWord.WdFootnoteLocation.wdBottomOfPage;
Options.NumberingRule = InteropWord.WdNumberingRule.wdRestartPage;
```

However, this gives the same error.

Comment: For which version of office document it gives error?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking, but it's a `.docx` file, created using the same interop library.

Comment: If you record a macro when performing the actions successfully within Word then compare the basic syntax to what you're using can you see any difference in the objects/properties/methods? And if you then run that macro does it execute successfully or generate an error (if yes, what)?

Comment: @CindyMeister: See my update.

Comment: This could be a change in 2016... We'd need more exact repro information in order to test. Can you tell us the most basic steps for how to set up the starting point (document) the code is running on?

Comment: @CindyMeister: Just seen your comment as I submitted my answer (below). Thanks for the help, I managed to re-code the C# interop code in a slightly different way. For now I'm happy with this solution although I might re-visit it as i'm still curious to know what it was about the generated document that the interop code, and word itself didn't like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure of the exact cause (possibly something further up in my code creating different sections); still not clear on why it worked when word recorded the macro, but not when running it.

Anyway, I managed to alter the C# code to the below, which seems to do the job and actually works!

```
foreach(InteropWord.Footnote FootNote in Doc.Footnotes)
{
    FootNote.Reference.FootnoteOptions.NumberingRule = InteropWord.WdNumberingRule.wdRestartPage;
    FootNote.Reference.FootnoteOptions.Location = InteropWord.WdFootnoteLocation.wdBottomOfPage;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, shame the error message isn't a bit more verbose, but oh well. Yup will accept, can't yet as i'm answering my own question.